# How to let gradle generate junit test result reports for custom sourceset?

Tags: scala, junit, gradle, specs2

I have set up a source set for functional testing in my project. Everything is working as expected, except the generation of junit test reports. I cannot see what configuration bit I am missing. Here is what I have:

```
sourceSets {
    // Note that just declaring this sourceset creates two configurations.
    funcTest {
        scala {
            srcDir 'src/funcTest/scala'
            compileClasspath += main.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    funcTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    funcTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

task funcTest(type:Test){
    description = "Run integration tests (located in src/funcTest/...)."
    testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.funcTest.output.classesDir
    testSrcDirs = project.sourceSets.funcTest.scala.source
    classpath = project.sourceSets.funcTest.runtimeClasspath
    dependsOn test
}
```

The above builds and runs my tests. However, the reports directory structure looks like this:

```
./build/reports/tests/No source file found at src/test/scala/com/hp/snapfish/ecommerce/taxservice/mongo/base-style.css
./build/reports/tests/No source file found at src/test/scala/com/hp/snapfish/ecommerce/taxservice/mongo/css3-pie-1.0beta3.htc
./build/reports/tests/No source file found at src/test/scala/com/hp/snapfish/ecommerce/taxservice/mongo/MongoConfigTest.html
./build/reports/tests/No source file found at src/test/scala/com/hp/snapfish/ecommerce/taxservice/mongo/MongoConfigTest.scala.html
./build/reports/tests/No source file found at src/test/scala/com/hp/snapfish/ecommerce/taxservice/mongo/report.js
./build/reports/tests/No source file found at src/test/scala/com/hp/snapfish/ecommerce/taxservice/mongo/style.css
```

What am I missing? Why is creating that

> No source file found at src

directory? I figure it needs to know that it should be looking for scala files, but I am not sure how to tell it that. I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this in your build.gradle file:

```
test {
    testLogging {
        // log results to "build/test-results" directory
        exceptionFormat "full"
        events "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
    }
}
```

Then, you should find output in a location like:  project-root/build/test-results .  I'm not sure how to do this on the "main" source trunk but this works for the "test" trunk.  If you have a unit test you can try this and maybe get a better idea.

Comment: `testLogging` only affects the console output.

Comment: What plugin is required for "testLogging" to work? I get "could not find method testLogging" when using this exact code in build.gradle while using android-test (junit).

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell where "No source file found at src" comes from, but try to set `testResultsDir` (XML) and `testReportDir` (HTML). You'll have to set these anyway as otherwise you'll be overwriting the files produced by the `test` task.

```
reports.junitXml.destination = "$buildDir/test-results/TaskName"  
reports.html.destination = "$buildDir/test-results/TaskName"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with scala specs (see https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/specs2-users/zxOWrMEL8rY). It is not a gradle issue. I need to do more investigation of specs2. Thanks for the suggestions.